# MS Access: Selecting records from 1 table based on multiple records of another table's field

Tags: sql, criteria

My question would be: How can I SELECT records of 1 table, based on another table's multiple records with a specific field value?

So I have 2 tables, both with 3 fields. Important to note, that [suti].[id] === [tartalom].[sutiid].

My job would be to select all [suti].[nev] and [suti].[tipus] that have both "G" and "To" in [tartalom].[mentes]. However, "G" and "To" are recorded in separate records, and that is why I have a problem with this.

In this example I have written below, the only record that should be selected is Something2 || tortaszelet.

How is this achieveable? Thank you for your help in advance :)

Before anybody says, it's not me that did this data structure. This is what I have, and cannot change it.

## Table 1: suti

### id || nev || tipus

---

1 || Something1 || torta 
2 || Something2 || tortaszelet 
3 || Something3 || pite

## Table 2: tartalom

### id || sutiid || mentes

---

1 || 1 || L 
2 || 1 || To 
3 || 2 || G 
4 || 2 || To 
5 || 3 || G

Comment: Please adjust the tags for just the database you are using.

Comment: MS Access does seem to be documented to support `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  But it may be limited to the kinds of expressions it can accept.

Answer (score 1):

All the following is standard SQL.

Simple aggregation to find the corresponding id:

```
SELECT sutiid
  FROM tartalom WHERE mentes IN ('G', 'To')
 GROUP BY sutiid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mentes) = 2
;
```

Now just join (not necessarily a join) this with the first table to obtain that row or rows.

```
SELECT *
  FROM suti
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT sutiid
       FROM tartalom
      WHERE mentes IN ('G', 'To')
      GROUP BY sutiid
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mentes) = 2
     )
;
```

Access doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`, but should handle this, which is also standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM suti
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT sutiid
       FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT sutiid AS sutiid, mentes
             FROM tartalom
            WHERE mentes IN ('G', 'To')
            ) xxx
      GROUP BY sutiid
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
     )
;
```

Comment: To this, access pops up syntax error on COUNT(DISTINCT mentes) = 2.

Comment: @user15813625 What is access?  :)   You tagged `sql`.  This is standard SQL.  With access, you'll probably need something different.  But you can use the above logic.

Comment: @user15813625 The last example avoids the COUNT(DISTINCT x) which Access appears not to support.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM suti
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT suited
       FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT sutiid AS sutiid, mentes
             FROM tartalom
            WHERE mentes IN ('G', 'To')
            ) xxx
      GROUP BY sutiid
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
     )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to restructure your solution. Here it is:

```
SELECT nev, tipus
 FROM suti, tartalom
  WHERE suti.id=sutiid
   AND (mentes="G" or mentes="To")
  GROUP BY nev, tipus
 HAVING Count(sutiid)=2;
```

Thank you :)

Comment: That looks ok, except that it doesn't protect from the case that 2 `tartalom` rows have the same `mentes` value, which we couldn't assume without your schema.  You would need an appropriate `UNIQUE constraint` to guarantee this.  My solution doesn't make any assumptions and will work without the constraint.  Yours may not. That was the reason for the initial `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`, and other similar, logic.  Also, we know nothing about the uniqueness of the `(nev, tipus)` pair.  That could be logically an error.